# Wordpress insert record if not exists and avoid duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hi i am trying to insert data to wordpress table its successfully added but it duplicates data each time page refreshed, i want to insert data if the is new otherwise do nothing

```
foreach ( $response->data as $single_data ) {

    // post title
    $post_title    = $single_data->name; 

    global $wpdb;

    //tablename
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

    $wpdb->insert($tablename,
        array(
            'post_type'  => 'vimeo_videos',
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s')
    );


}
```

Comment: You can verify `post_name` field and `post_type` before inserting the new record and I suggest you to use `wp_insert_post` function which will properly make `post_name` from title and that will help you to identify the existing record, and WordPress using sanitized title to generate post name  more info - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: Where's the code to check anything? What have you tried to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I created an array and tried this. Successfully inserted data into database. Please make it as you got your array. I hope it will be helpful for you

```
$response = array("title"=>array("title one",'title two'));
//echo "<pre>";print_r($response);echo "</pre>";exit();
foreach ( $response['title'] as $single_data ) {
    $post_title    = $single_data;
    global $wpdb;
    $allPosts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $post_title ) .'%') );
//echo "<pre>";print_r($allPosts);echo "</pre>";exit();

if (count($allPosts) == 0) {
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $wpdb->insert($tablename,
        array(
            'post_type'  => 'vimeo_videos',
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        ),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s')
    );
} else {
    /*Do whatever you like */
}
```

}

Comment: The above did not work can you please give any other solution

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try again and let me know if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response
I have found solution like this and it works fine

foreach ( $response->data as $single_data ) {

```
$post_title    = $single_data->name; 

if (!post_exists($post_title)) { // Determine if a post exists based on title, content, and date
    $post_id = array(
        'post_type'  => 'vimeo_videos',
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
     );

}
$newPostID = wp_insert_post($post_id);
```

}